# Iterate over dataset after all data has been fetched

Tags: angular, ionic2

On my page have a method that is fetching data from a server using a rxjs service and saving them to a Set.

When I'm trying to iterate over them in the view and apply a Pipe I noticed that the pipe code is called before the full dataset is loaded. I managed to make the iteration wait with an

```
<ion-list *ngIf="mySet.size > 1">
```

but the size is unknown. How can I wait for the full dataset to load before applying the pipe and iterating?

Comment: Please show how you load the dataset. Why do you think it's not fully loaded at once? Why do you think it matters that it is fully loaded before iteration?

Comment: Dataset is composed of several asynchronous requests. Nothing fancy about it. If I omit the ngIf nothing is displayed since the Pipe is called with an empty Set and returns back an empty Set...

Comment: Well, if you want to load it "all at once", you'll have to modify the code that you don't want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create boolean that will be true only once the data is loaded.

```
isDataLoaded
```

and then in your template do:

```
<ion-list *ngIf="isDataLoaded">
```